# Flex: CollectionChangeEvent cannot be triggered by removeAll()

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, arraycollection

the code is like the following:

---

```
[Bindable]
public var abc_list:ArrayCollection;

...

this.abc_list.removeAll();
this.abc_list.addAll(otherCollection);

...

this.abclist.addEventListener(CollectionChangeEvent.COLLECTION_CHANGE, onCollectionChange)
```

---

I found that the event cannot be triggered after the moment of removeAll(), but it works well in addAll(otherCollection) [with event.type].

So the original list is not removed before the new list is added;And the abc_list is actually accumulated?!

Why is it happen? and What can I do with that?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  I get a collection change if the removeAll(); is triggered.  Is it that you want an event to fire for each function?

Answer (score 0):

May be hacky and I'm thinking this out loud as I haven't checked it

```
this.abc_list.removeAll();
this.abc_list.refresh()
```

and wait for a CollectionEvent event with the CollectionEventKind.REFRESH upon refresh

Comment: is it the flex problem that removeAll() sometimes cannot actually remove the list of dataProvider?

Answer (score 0):

*this.abclist.addEventListener(**CollectionChangeEvent.COLLECTION_CHANGE**, onCollectionChange)*

Is it custom event ?

I am using CollectionEvent.COLLECTION_CHANGE and it works fine with removeAll() method. I hope using CollectionEvent.COLLECTION_CHANGE solves your problem.

Comment: sorry; it should be CollectionEvent NOT CollectionChangeEvent